# Putting a whole Facebook application in the timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

For a project, I have been asked to put a complete Facebook application inside the timeline. However, I cannot find any information about this in the Facebook reference. Does anybody know if it can be done?

Comment: What does it mean to "put a complete Facebook application inside the timeline"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your client wants to use the new [Add To TimeLine](https://www.facebook.com/about/timeline/apps) feature. [This](https://www.facebook.com/help?faq=105925952849619) provides another introduction from user perspective.

As an example, this image shows Spotify, NetFlix and Nike app implementations of the new feature on the timeline:

[image: apps on timeline]

You can implement a basic "add to timeline" functionality using the JavaScript SDK although API [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/add-to-timeline/) is limited.

You can also create customized app contents and aggregate contents ("movies watched this month on Netflix") for the Timeline by integrating your app with the Open Graph. Facebook has [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) introductory tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. However, it looks like the "Add To Timeline" plugin doesn't allow me to change what is going to be displayed in the box (currently, it only shows the last timeline updates by my app). Is there anything I can do to customize the content?

Comment: I've edited my answer by adding a link to a FB tutorial on how to get started customizing apps on the Timeline.

Comment: The only way to customise the content is to create new aggregations of the same data. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-units/

Answer (score 1):

Probably you talking about Page Tab application for pages with Timeline.

Read the tutorial for [Page Tab applications](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) and documentation for [Add to Page dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/).

For personal profiles applications in timeline is only section dedicated to actions and activities published by application to user.