# How to create non-canvas Facebook App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Putting a whole Facebook application in the timeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227670/putting-a-whole-facebook-application-in-the-timeline)

There are some apps on Facebook which does not use Canvas but they leverage Facebook Timeline well; Tumblr, ESPN, Feedly, GoodReads and name a few. They don't have Canvas but they only post the User's Activity in Timeline (Such as 'read article', 'viewed article'). I'm looking forward to create such app. Even if you search for those Apps in Facebook you will be redirected to respective website.

I've been through Facebook Documentation but its a pain. All the docs, videos and articles I read were regarding Canvas Apps however an article from [insidefacebook](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/04/22/canvas-connect-websites-best/) gave me some idea about Facebook Apps still no success.

Can anyone please help with that?

Comment: Ohh I see. These Facebook API is so confusing. Anyways thanks for the answer. But please post this comment as an answer so that I can close this question (and award you some points too :p )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To integrate your app with the [Facebook TimeLine](https://www.facebook.com/about/timeline/apps), you need to use the [Open Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

The Open Graph API enables users to performed more specific, high-level social actions beyond comment, like and share. For example, instead of posting a link to a review via the Graph API, a movie review app can with the Open Graph API allow users to "review" "action movies","comedies", etc. A book reader app can allow users to share when they "started reading" and "finished reading" a "Russian novel".

To implement an Open Graph app, you need to define [object and actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/) for your app. Objects can be selected from [existing object types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/) e.g. "video" or you can implement your own app-specific [custom object types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/), e.g. "action movie". Actions can be [built in action types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/) e.g. "watch" or [custom action types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/), e.g. "started reading".

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) is a step-by-step tutorial on Facebook Developer on how to get started with your Open Graph app.